# How to make rooftext effect and valley text effect in HTML5 (or Fabric.js)

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using below code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
/// (c) Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen, Abidas Software .com
/// License: CC-Attribute

var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    font = '64px impact',
    w = demo.width,
    h = demo.height,
    curve,
    offsetY,
    bottom,
    textHeight,
    angleSteps = 255/h,
    i = h,
    y,
    os = document.createElement('canvas'),
    octx = os.getContext('2d');

os.width = w;
os.height = h;
octx.font = font;
octx.textBaseline = 'top';
octx.textAlign = 'center';

function renderBridgeText() {
    curve = parseInt(iCurve.value, 10);
    offsetY = parseInt(iOffset.value, 10);
    textHeight = parseInt(iHeight.value, 10);
    bottom = parseInt(iBottom.value, 10);

    vCurve.innerHTML = curve;
    vOffset.innerHTML = offsetY;
    vHeight.innerHTML = textHeight;
    vBottom.innerHTML = bottom;

    octx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    octx.fillText(iText.value, w * 0.5, 0);

    /// slide and dice
    i = w;
    while (i--) {
        y = bottom + curve * Math.sin(i / angleSteps * Math.PI /160);
        ctx.drawImage(os, i, offsetY, 1, textHeight,i,offsetY, 1, y);
    }
}
iCurve.onchange = iOffset.onchange = iHeight.onchange = iBottom.onchange = iText.onkeyup = renderBridgeText;
renderBridgeText()
}//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id=demo width=600 height=300></canvas>
<br>
    <span>Curve:</span>
<input id="iCurve" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=110>
<span id="vCurve">110</span>
    <br><span>OffsetY:</span>
<input id="iOffset" type="range" min=0 max=100 value=4>
<span id="vOffset">0</span>
    <br><span>Text height:</span>
<input id="iHeight" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=64>
<span id="vHeight">64</span>
    <br><span>Bottom:</span>
<input id="iBottom" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=200>
<span id="vBottom">200</span>
<br><span>Text:</span>
<input id="iText" type="text" value="BRIDGE TEXT">
</body>
```

I need the text effect like below images,I have tried a lot to make this but i cannot.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me out?

Also can we use active object from fabric.js with context?

Comment: Take a look at the 3D transform propeties and with the perspective-origin() you might can get this effect. No time to show a jsFiddle ;P Some info: http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware I am just asking for some guidance how to use those context properties with active objects of fabric.js

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware okay I will add another question for fabric.js. thanks for helping in this

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a modified version of the original code (the provided code in question has changed values compared to my original code.. .-) ) which can produce all these shapes just by playing around with the parameters:

[image: Valley]

[image: Roof]

[image: Roof inversed]

[image: Bridge]

The roof is not super but I'll leave it to you to add scaling support as this is meant as an example.

**[ONLINE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/e8hZy/)**

**Initialization**:

```
var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'), /// context
    font = '64px impact',        /// font
    w = demo.width,              /// cache canvas width and height
    h = demo.height,
    curve,                       /// radius
    offsetY,                     /// offset for text
    bottom,                      /// bottom of text
    textHeight,                  /// text height (region of text)
    isTri = false,               /// is triangle shaped (roof)
    dltY,                        /// delta for triangle
    angleSteps = 180 / w,        /// angle steps for curved text
    i = w,                       /// "x" backwards
    y,                           /// top of text

    /// offscreen canvas that holds original text
    os = document.createElement('canvas'),
    octx = os.getContext('2d');

os.width = w;
os.height = h;

/// set font on off-screen canvas where we draw it
octx.font = font;
octx.textBaseline = 'top';
octx.textAlign = 'center';
```

**Main function**:

```
/// render
function renderBridgeText() {

    /// demo stuff snipped (see link)

    /// clear canvases    
    octx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    /// draw text (text may change)
    octx.fillText(iText.value.toUpperCase(), w * 0.5, 0);

    /// slide and dice
    dltY = curve / textHeight;  /// calculate delta for roof/triangle
    y = 0;                      /// reset y in case we do roof
    i = w;                      /// init "x"

    while (i--) {

        if (isTri) {
            /// bounce delta value mid-way for triangle
            y += dltY;
            if (i === (w * 0.5)|0) dltY = -dltY;

        } else {
            /// calc length based on radius+angle for curve
            y = bottom - curve * Math.sin(i * angleSteps * Math.PI / 180);
        }

        /// draw a slice
        ctx.drawImage(os, i, 0, 1, textHeight,
                          i, h * 0.5 - offsetY / textHeight * y, 1, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using above same properties can you tell me how to use them for active objects of fabric.js?

Comment: @Rash sorry, I am not familiar with fabric (your question wasn't tagged with fabric.js either). Don't forget to up-vote/accept if answer was helpful.

Comment: How did you even come up with this?

Comment: ... and to use this nice effect with FabricJS: Create a new Fabric.Image(myNativeCanvasWithCurvedText) to display your arched text.

Comment: If the above online demo link doesn't works for you, please click on this link: https://codepen.io/vinayofficial/pen/XWKKaNG

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Above answer helped me a lot.
But while working in typescript. I've faced issue while passing the simple text image in 'drawImage' function.

So, below is the modified changes of the above code as per the typescript/angular.

Html:

```
   <canvas #simpleText id="simpleText" width=220 height=80></canvas>
   <canvas #myCanvas id="myCanvas" width=800 height=400></canvas>
```

Initialization:

```
     @ViewChild('myCanvas', {static: false}) myCanvas: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
    context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

    @ViewChild('simpleText', {static: false}) simpleText: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;
    simpleTextContext: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    
    // default values
    shapeConfigure:any={
        w : null,
        h : null,
        curve: 10 ,
        offsetY: 50,
        bottom: 200,
        textHeight: 64,
        isTri : false,
        angleSteps : 0
    };

    // canvas width height
    shapeCanvas={
        w: 800,
        h: 400
    }        
    iText:string = 'check text';
    sampleImage = new Image();
    dataURL:any='';

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.context = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
        var font = '60px impact';

        this.simpleTextContext = this.simpleText.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
        this.simpleText.nativeElement.height=60;
        this.simpleText.nativeElement.width=400;
        this.simpleTextContext.font = font;
        this.simpleTextContext.textBaseline = 'top';
        this.simpleTextContext.textAlign = 'left';
        this.simpleTextContext.fillText(this.iText.toUpperCase(), 200* 0.5, 0);

        this.dataURL = this.simpleText.nativeElement.toDataURL();
        console.log(this.dataURL);
        this.sampleImage.src = this.dataURL;    

        this.shapeConfigure={
            w : this.myCanvas.nativeElement.width,
            h : this.myCanvas.nativeElement.height,
            curve: 10 ,
            offsetY: 50,
            bottom: 200,
            textHeight: 64,
            isTri : false,
            angleSteps : 180 /this.shapeCanvas.w
        }

        this.renderBridgeText(false);
    }
```

Main Function:

```
        renderBridgeText(textChange) {     

        var curve = parseInt(this.shapeConfigure.curve, 10);
        var offsetY = parseInt(this.shapeConfigure.offsetY, 10);
        var textHeight = parseInt(this.shapeConfigure.textHeight, 10);
        var bottom = parseInt(this.shapeConfigure.bottom, 10);
        var isTri = this.shapeConfigure.isTri;

        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.shapeCanvas.w , this.shapeCanvas.h );

        if(textChange){
        this.simpleTextContext.clearRect(0, 0, this.shapeCanvas.w , this.shapeCanvas.h );
        this.simpleTextContext.fillText(this.iText.toUpperCase(), 200* 0.5, 0);
        this.dataURL = this.simpleText.nativeElement.toDataURL();
        }
        this.sampleImage.src = this.dataURL;


        this.sampleImage.onload = () => {
        /// slide and dice
        var i:number = this.shapeCanvas.w;
        var dltY:number = curve / textHeight;
        var y = 0;
        while (i--) {
            if (isTri) {
                y += dltY;
                if (i === (this.shapeCanvas.w * 0.5))
                    dltY = -dltY;
            } else {
                y = bottom - curve * Math.sin(i * this.shapeConfigure.angleSteps * Math.PI / 180);
            }
            
            this.context.drawImage(this.sampleImage, i, 0, 1, textHeight, i, this.shapeCanvas.h * 0.5 - offsetY / textHeight * y, 1, y);
        }
        }
    }
```