# Horizontally scaled font via drawText?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Is there an elegant way to put text in canvas via drawText, so that it is squeezed horizontally/vertically?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544735/how-to-make-rooftext-effect-and-valley-text-effect-in-html5-or-fabric-js/19553200#19553200) can give some inspiration/hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Elegant?, Well...Kind of yes!"

You can scale the canvas horizontally and the text will be squeezed.

```
ctx.scale(.80,1);
ctx.fillText("Squeezed!",15/.80,30);
ctx.scale(-0.80,1);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Seems like a right path, but let me clarify. My canvas contains other graphics, and it shouldn't be modified. CTX in your code is a canvas? I have hard time searching for filltext method...

Comment: You're welcome :-) `ctx` is the context object associated with a canvas element. In my example, the canvas is **temporarily squeezed** to 80% but after drawing the text with `context.fillText` the example **unsqueezes** the canvas so all new drawings will not be squeezed. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Appreciate it, sir. I'm trying to get text as if it were written on a slope that user sees from an upper point.