# How to create Text WordArt In Canvas (FabricJS)

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm creating a product designer using [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com/). Is there any way to create wordart text shapes in canvas. Just like we have [Text Wordarts](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=wordart%20in%20ms%20word&biw=1366&bih=629&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIsseSwa63yAIVFZGOCh0o7AnF) in Microsoft Word.

I searched online but didn't find anything. I have used [Fabric curvedText](https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText) library though and it provides functionality to only rotate text. Is there anyway or library to create text wordart in different shapes?

Comment: FabricJS doesn't draw text in the way you want it curved. Here's a previous SO answer showing how to do curved text in native canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544735/how-to-make-rooftext-effect-and-valley-text-effect-in-html5-or-fabric-js/19553200#19553200.

Comment: You can do it only with svg text on path but unfortunately fabricjs doesn't provide support for text on path yet. @markE 's amswer would be a possible workaround. But that is also not straight forward way to work with fabricjs but the normal html canvas api.