# overlaping canvas a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

is it possible to combine a canvas and a div i have tried to work them together but i cant get it to work

here is my Div

```
    <div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
    <span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
    <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
     </div>
```

this is canvas

```
    <canvas id=demo width=400 height=300></canvas>
```

here is the complete code it is not mine please view [How to make rooftext effect and valley text effect in HTML5 (or Fabric.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544735/how-to-make-rooftext-effect-and-valley-text-effect-in-html5-or-fabric-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place both in a container and use absolute positioning, as so:

```
<div id="container">

<canvas id=demo width=400 height=300></canvas>

<div href="#" class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
<span data-bind="click:$parent.remove">[x]</span><br/><br/>
<center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center>
</div>

</div>
```

and then in the style sheet:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#demo, div[href="#"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: .container {
 width: 500px;
         height: 500px;
        border: 2px solid;
    position: relative; 
 overflow: auto;
  }
canvas, div[href="#"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    }

Comment: You can adjust the positioning as you please; I used 0 and 0 so they'd overlap in top left corner, as an example. :)

Comment: one last question are you still there?

Comment: how can i manipulate the font size of font = '64px impact', to id="size" i want to let the user change the size as he wishes

Comment: If you have further questions please open up another question and be more specific.

Comment: let me make another question ill send you the link please wait