# Create an arc text using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there any way to create an arc text using canvas? I followed the answer our here:

[How to make rooftext effect and valley text effect in HTML5 (or Fabric.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544735/how-to-make-rooftext-effect-and-valley-text-effect-in-html5-or-fabric-js)

Best thing I got was curve from roof or bottom. Is there any any to create an arc in canvas?

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
  font-size: 35px;
}

path {
  fill: transparent;
}

text {
  fill: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 425 300">
  <path id="curve" d="M6,150C49.63,93,105.79,36.65,156.2,47.55,207.89,58.74,213,131.91,264,150c40.67,14.43,108.57-6.91,229-145" />
  <text x="25">
    <textPath xlink:href="#curve">
      Dangerous Curves Ahead
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for making text to apper in arc.

```js
function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle) {
        var len = str.length, s;
        context.save();
        context.translate(centerX, centerY);
        context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
        context.rotate(-1 * (angle / len) / 2);
        for(var n = 0; n < len; n++) {
          context.rotate(angle / len);
          context.save();
          context.translate(0, -1 * radius);
          s = str[n];
          context.fillText(s, 0, 0);
          context.restore();
        }
        context.restore();
      }
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'), 
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        centerX = canvas.width / 2,
        centerY = canvas.height - 30,
        angle = Math.PI * 0.8,
        radius = 150;
      
      context.font = '30pt Calibri';
      context.textAlign = 'center';
      context.fillStyle = 'red';
      context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
      context.lineWidth = 4;
      drawTextAlongArc(context, 'Arc Canvas Text', centerX, centerY, radius, angle);

      // draw circle underneath text
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius - 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.stroke();
```

```css
#canvas{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="250"></canvas>
```